# Reactor will operations on a flux occur in order?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

If I have two flatmaps on a flux will the they always execute in sequence

```
Flux.just(1,2,3,4)
    .flatMap(...) 
    .flatMap(...) // Will this always execute 2nd?
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what exactly you mean - specifics are important here.

**For any given element** the answer is yes - it will be processed by the first flatMap call, then the results of that flatMap call processed by the second flatMap call. Recall that operators in reactor, similar to vanilla Java streams, are chained - so there's no sensible way they could ever operate out of sequence.

For all elements in total though, no - as in it won't process the first flatMap call for all 4 elements, then process the second flatMap call for all 4 elements - each element is treated independently. When you consider that a Flux is analogous to a stream of elements that may have no end, rather than a defined, bounded collection, it wouldn't make much sense if it didn't behave this way.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider these small examples :

```java
Flux.just(3, 2, 1)
  .flatMap(e -> {
    System.out.println("First FlatMap : " + e);
    return Mono.just(e).delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(e * 100));
  })
  .flatMap(e -> {
    System.out.println("Second FlatMap : " + e);
    return Mono.just(e);
  })
  .blockLast();

/*
First FlatMap : 3
First FlatMap : 2
First FlatMap : 1
Second FlatMap : 1
Second FlatMap : 2
Second FlatMap : 3
*/
```

```java
Flux.just(3, 2, 1)
  .flatMap(e -> {
    System.out.println("First FlatMap : " + e);
    return Mono.just(e);
  })
  .flatMap(e -> {
    System.out.println("Second FlatMap : " + e);
    return Mono.just(e);
  })
  .blockLast();

/*
First FlatMap : 3
Second FlatMap : 3
First FlatMap : 2
Second FlatMap : 2
First FlatMap : 1
Second FlatMap : 1
*/
```

We can say an operator process the elements in the order they came in.